# In Django Models, At Admin Area, how to auto assign the 'requesting' user to one of the foreign key User relation field

Tags: python, django, web

In the following mode in my project, I want to assign the `author` variable of class upon the creation of model, on user end this could be done via `request.user` but as  the class can be only instantiated from the admin area, this doesn't work.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
 title  =  models.CharField(max_length=300)
 content = RichTextField()

 author =  models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="Author", auto_created= True, on_delete= 
 models.CASCADE)
 date =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`auto_created=…`** field <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.auto_created) is about *model inheritance*, it does not add the logged in user: the model layer is request unaware, and there is not per se a "logged in user". You thus remodel this to:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = RichTextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='blogs',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False,
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In the model admin for the `Blog` model, you can work with:

```
from django.contrib import admin


@admin.register(Blog)
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Blog` model to the `User`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`Author`</s> relation to `blogs`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).